# Check external application preferences Unity 2020

Tags: unity3d

Помогите! Не открываются скрипты в Unity 2020
что делать?
Не могу открыть си шарп
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Опишите проблему точнее. Какие скрипты? Какие действия вы делаете для открытия? Не открываются, т.е. есть какие-то ошибки? Приведите всё это в вопросе с помощью кнопки править

Comment: Выше отправил фото. Взгляните пожалуйста. выдаёт ошибку Unable to open Assets/Scripts/PlayerController.cs: Check external application preferences" error

Comment: Добавьте ошибку текстом в вопрос. Вы сделали, что советуют — *Check external application preferences*? Если да, то также опишите это в вопросе

Comment: Посмотрите edit->preferences->external tools короче

Comment: Открыл. External Script Editor менять? там Open by file extension. пытаюсь поменять на browes и не находит в папке скрипт где он находится